# Is there any reason I should include a header in the associated cpp file if the former only provides declarations the latter defines?

Tags: c++, include, header-files, declaration, translation-unit

Consider a `foo.cpp` file with the following content

```cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
int foo() {
    return 7;
}
```

and its associated header

```cpp
#pragma once
int foo();
```

The latter is obviously needed to make aware the following `main` function of the existence of `foo`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.hpp" // to make the name `foo` available

int main() {
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
}
```

However, the `#include "foo.hpp"` seems to be redundant. Is there any reason I should keep it?

---

I've seen this practice in the codebase where I work on, but I guess there's many examples available in open source. For instance, as an example picked at random, look at [`src/builtin_builtin.h`](https://github.com/Aster89/fish-shell/blob/master/src/builtin_builtin.h) and [`src/builtin_bultin.cpp`](https://github.com/Aster89/fish-shell/blob/master/src/builtin_builtin.cpp) from the [`fish-shell` code base](https://github.com/Aster89/fish-shell): the former, beside the include guard, has
just

1. one `#include`,
2. two class declarations,
3. and a function declaration.

One could put 2 in a fwd header, include it in the cpp file together with 1, and then the cpp file wouldn't need anymore to include its own header.

Comment: what is a "fwd header" ?

Comment: It's a good way to make sure that the definition and declaration stays in sync (depending on changes can be picked up by a static analyzer, maybe not the compiler itself). It's also a way to add other common structures and declarations or definitions that might be needed (from the Fish files you link to there's for example the `parser_t` and `io_streams_t` types).

Comment: when something is necessary in 99% of the cases, its simpler to do the same in 100% of the cases. I'd rather ask "Is there any good reason to remove the include?" Once the source file is modified in a way that needs the header you have to add it anyhow.  Imho this boils down to being purely opinionbased.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, I was just curious, but I agree on the "if you do 99, then do 100". As reagrds _fwd header_ I really meant a header that make a declaration of those two classes in the linked example.

Comment: It is common to include the .hpp *first* in the corresponding .cpp file, to see that the header in fact compiles without dependencies. Some people even use an *empty* .cpp file, if necessary, just to perform this test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some reasons to include the header (`fpp.hpp`) from its implementation file (`fpp.cpp`):

1. If you include `foo.hpp` *first* in `foo.cpp`, then compilation of `foo.cpp` acts as a test that `foo.hpp` is [self-contained](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Self_contained_Headers), meaning it can be successfully compiled without including anything else first.  The Google C++ coding guidelines specifically recommend [including the associated header first](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Names_and_Order_of_Includes).
2. It is good practice for `foo.hpp` to declare everything that `foo.cpp` exports, and for everything else in `foo.cpp` to have [internal linkage](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Internal_Linkage) in order to not pollute the global namespace.  The GCC option [`-Wmissing-declarations`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html) will report deviations from that practice, but it only works if `foo.cpp` includes `foo.hpp`.
3. Sometimes (often, in fact), including `foo.hpp` is needed so `foo.cpp` will compile.  Most commonly, `foo.hpp` defines a type that `foo.cpp` needs, but it can also happen that function declarations are needed due to use before definition.  I recommend to just do so consistently rather than trying to deduce whether it's necessary in each case.
4. Occasionally, the compiler can diagnose mismatches between declarations and definitions.  A nasty case I've seen is a header declaring a global `int x` but the implementation file defining `long x`.  Waste a day debugging that mistake, and I predict you'll resolve to include the associated header every time thereafter!

Finally, there are no good reasons *not* to include the associated header.  In particular, omitting that include will almost never make a measurable difference to compile time.  There *are* ways of dramatically improving compile times by restructuring header dependencies (for example, use of [forward headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225910/what-are-the-uses-of-entire-headers-for-forward-declarations)), but this isn't one of them.

Acknowledgments: Point 1 was noted by BoP in a comment.  [MSalters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73248821/2659307) notes points 3 and 4.

Comment: Point 4 is much more relevant for C code. In C++ a mismatch will more likely just add a function overload.

Answer (score 3):

C++ processes files in linear order. If your .cpp file calls other methods from the same .cpp file, the definitions need to proceed the calls, else you need the declarations from the .hpp. And with two mutually recursive functions, you do need at least one declaration up front.

Additionally, having class declarations available means that the compiler can warn about mismatches (won't work with free function declarations, due to overloading)

Comment: *"won't work with free function declarations, due to overloading"* It will work, but only to a limited extend: `double foo() { ... }` would result in a compiler error as would `int foo() noexcept { ... }` or `int __stdcall foo() { ... }` It just cannot check for matching function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found there's a core guideline about it,

> #### [SF.5: A `.cpp` file must include the header file(s) that defines its interface](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#sf5-a-cpp-file-must-include-the-header-files-that-defines-its-interface)

which does mention some of the points the other answers are about.