# Proper use of of typedef in C++

Tags: c++, typedef

I have coworkers who occasionally use typedef to avoid typing. For example:

```
typedef std::list<Foobar> FoobarList;
...
FoobarList GetFoobars();
```

Personally, I always hate coming across code like this, largely because it forces me to go lookup the typedef so I can tell how to use it. I also feel like this sort of thing is a potential slippery slope... If you do this, why aren't you doing it more? (pretty soon, your code is totally obfuscated). I found this SO question regarding this issue:

[When should I use typedef in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516237/)

I have two questions:

1. am I truly alone in disliking this?
2. If the vast majority of people think this sort of typedef use is OK, what criteria do you use to determine whether to typedef a type?

Comment: This is a subjective question.  I think it would work better as community wiki.

Comment: It may not be to "save typing" - it may be to define "types" so that you are using a name for an object that specifies what it is and hides implementation.

Comment: I would object more to the use of the empty parenthesis for the default constructor than the typedef!

Comment: @Clifford: That's a function declaration.

Comment: @sbi: I must be asleep.  I think I assumed as an example of use of a defined type that one would show and object declaration!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The two big arguments for this type of `typedef` are the reduced typing, which you've already mentioned, and the ease of changing over to a new type of container.  A FoobarList could be backed by a `vector` or a `list` or a `deque` and switching would often just require changing a typedef.

Your dislike of them when it comes to looking them up, is quite reduced when dealing with IDEs, since I can just hover over the type name, and the IDE tells me what it's defined as.

The more useful situations are when you have nested containers - you can give the names some semantic meaning without having to define entire classes:

```
typedef std::list<Foobar> FoobarList;
typedef std::map <string, FoobarList> GizmosToFoobarsMap;
```

You can also save a LOT of typing when dealing with iterators of these types  (although that's reduced now that C++0x has `auto`.)

Comment: Unless your typedef is masking a trivial difference, wouldn't a change of container also necessitate a lot of code change regardless of the typedef?

Comment: Not if the change in container shares the same interface with the existing container. For example, STL containers such as `vector` and `list` have `begin()` and `end()` methods to access the container's elements.

Comment: For the most part, if you're using standard containers, you can switch back and forth pretty easily.  But admittedly, it's kind of a contrived situation, since I've maybe made such a change twice in my life.

Comment: I've done this in the past, but usually only exactly because I'm changing the (API-similar) definition of thing and don't want to go change all of the appearances of std::vector<foo> to std::list<foo>.  Typedefs for the win.  **Regardless,** one's decisions should be made to increase the comprehensibility of a bit of code, and as such, the actual meaning of the typedef should be irrelevant beyond what the name itself tells you about the thing.  E.g. I don't really care if FooList is a std::list or a std::vector when I use it, unless I need to do a bunch of inserts or random acces.

Comment: The biggest code change when switching types without typedefs would often be in layers that don't even use the types and just pass it around.

Comment: If you have code that is truly independent of container implementation (whether just passing it around, or using the more general concepts only - e.g. just `begin` and `end`), why not go all the way and make it properly generic by making it a template?

Comment: @Pavel: Oftentimes, to achieve that level of independance, the code is based on templates.  However, the templates are parameterized on the container's iterator, not the container itself.  If, for some reason, you decided to parameterize on the container, you've done nothing more than give a fancy name to the typedef you seem to dislike.  And you've probably made your code more complex in the process; if you store the container in an object of your own, for instance, now that entire structure has to be generic.

Answer (score 10):

`typedef`s are essential to STL and template programming in general. Just look at how iterator traits work:

```
template <class Iterator>
struct iterator_traits {
  typedef typename Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category;
  typedef typename Iterator::value_type        value_type;
  typedef typename Iterator::difference_type   difference_type;
  typedef typename Iterator::pointer           pointer;
  typedef typename Iterator::reference         reference;
};

template <class T>
struct iterator_traits<T*> {
  typedef random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
  typedef T                          value_type;
  typedef ptrdiff_t                  difference_type;
  typedef T*                         pointer;
  typedef T&                         reference;
};
```

As for "shortcut" usage of `typedef`s - I think it's perfectly fine when localized in an implementation file. I have the same rule here as for `using namespace` - if it saves me typing and doesn't confuse others, go for it.

Comment: +1 that's what i was looking for. Just one more (maybe stupid) question. Are there any drawbacks acting like this?

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand your question. Acting like what?

Comment: using `typedef` this way. however... obviously not :). Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I like typedefs like that because they improve readability.  Consider having `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator` all over the place, or even `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >::iterator`.  Half your code ends up just describing types, and a bunch of typedefs simplifies that a lot.  I don't think it's too much of a hurdle to understanding either - IDEs can usually tell you the type if you hover the mouse over it or go-to-definition, and working with code usually requires you understand things like this anyway.

Answer (score 5):

***I like that `typedef`*** because it allows to ***change the type of the container*** later (say, profiling showed `std::deque` to be faster than `std::list`) ***without changing all the code in question***.

And in case you wonder: I don't object to the thing being called a list, even though it might be a `std::deque`. In this context I see "list" as a conceptual term, not a data structure. (You don't do your shopping lists as doubly linked lists, do you?)

Comment: In practice, it's rarely possible to change type of a container like that - e.g. `deque` has `operator[]`, while `list` has not; `deque` iterators are random-access, so they work with some algorithms which don't work for `list`; and so on.

Comment: @Pavel: So take `std::vector` and `std::deque` instead. The principle still holds.

Comment: @Pavel: However, as others have mentioned, most of your code won't care.  Its just passing around variables, or using constructs that don't change.  And those bits that do matter will show up right away when your code fails to compile.  The biggest concern in my experience is when an algorithm is specialized for random access iterators, but still operates with forward iterators; in that case, the profiling that suggested changing containers might suggest changing back.

Comment: Hence why I wrote "in practice". In practice, I've yet to see a case where I wanted to replace a vector with a deque, or vice versa. More realistically, you'd want to e.g. replace vector with list, or even replace vector with set or map - which normally involves rewriting a lot more code, in any case.

Comment: @Pavel: In practice I have once replaced `std::map<T1,T2>` with `std::vector< std::pair<T1,T2> >`. I had to change surprisingly little code.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I also `typedef` STL stuff, the list and the iterator (`Foos` and `FooIterator`). Used everywhere makes for a very clear (imo) style that you get used to by the 2nd occurance.

Besides you can just mouse over the type to see what it really means in any real IDE (vs or eclipse), so you have all the information you need right at its point of use in addition to not having to scroll 3 screens to the right just to read the full line.

With the C++0x `auto` keyword this won't be needed anymore. Yes, I'm a believer in C#'s `var` keyword, and again you can mouse over it to see the type if you're in doubt!

Answer (score 2):

I don't do that in my code either, so I guess you are not alone. To my mind it makes one more thing that the reader has to go look up. The poor code reader generally has more than enough of those already.

Comment: Ideally, your IDE/editor takes care of this. For example, in Visual Studio, you just hover the mouse over the typedef, and a tooltip is displayed, describing what the typedef is.

Comment: @Ben, perhaps. But even then, I now have to remember "Oh yeah, `FoobarList` is a `std::list` of `Foobar` (not `Foobar *` mind you, just plain `Foobar`). I'm sure that's no problem for lots of folks, but I can only hold so many such things in my head at once while trying to figure out code.

Comment: Agreed. It becomes even more incomprehensible with maps - you end up having `MapStringToFoobar` and `MapIntToFoobar` and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

In your example `FoobarList` is no different from any other class; you'd still have to look the definition or documentation to know how to use it; and you would not use that as an argument for not using classes!

In this case once you'd determined that it was an STL std::list, you'd know how to use it or at least where to find good quality documentation; which is probably more than you can say for most classes that may be defined in your project.

That said I am ambivalent as to whether it is a good idea or not; I just think that it is mostly harmless.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find that typedefs are very useful when dealing with templated code, both when writing templates, and when instantiating them.

Writing templates:

typedefs are required for template metaprogramming. For Example, removing const:

```
template<typename T>
struct RemoveConst
{
typedef T Type;
};

template<>
struct RemoveConst<const T>
{
typedef T Type;
};
```

Now, we can access the const-less type from any T by instantiating RemoveConst::Type

Instantiating templates:

Like a lot of things in programming, right tool for the right job.
typedefs such as your example

```
typedef std::list<Foobar> FoobarList;
...
FoobarList GetFoobars();
```

Sound completely reasonable, mainly because the typedefed name is descriptive(a FoobarList is a List of Foobars). This is very useful particularly when dealing with STL containers, or any other template types that share the same interface. imagine the following class declaration:

```
class SomeClass
{
...
std::vector<int> mContainer;
};
```

This class is likely to iterate over the elements of Container, which would result in code similar to:

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator It = mContainer.begin(); It != mContainer.end(); ++It)
{
}
```

Now imagine that you realize, after writing the above for-loop in 5 different metods, that you are constantly inserting in the middle of the array, and that a std::list would be much better suited for the job.
In this case, you would have to go through every instance of std::vector::iterator, and change the declaration.

Instead, What you can do, is typedef the container you are using inside the class:

```
class SomeClass
{
typedef std::vector<int> IntContainer;
...
IntContainer mContainer;
};
```

This can allow you to write highly generic code, that can be very easily modifiable.

```
for(IntContainer::iterator It = mContainer.begin(); It != mContainer.end(); ++It)
{
}
```

In this case, you only need to change the typedef of IntContainer, and any instance that refers to it, is automatically changed.

Answer (score 0):

You see typedefs a lot when you need to write C++ code that works across platforms, because the size of the fundamental datatypes are not fixed. For example, the Java virtual machine has typedefs for the fundamental types for different compilers.

Comment: True, although I'll add that `<stdint.h>` use typedefs to achieve what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think the typedef is good practice in this case. While the template syntax puts the parameters in you face, they are usually the sort of things one would try to encapsulate in an object oriented environment.

typedef'ing the template performs that encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If I want the ending type to be strongly typed, I typically prefer inheritance over typedef, e.g.
`class CMyMap : public CMap<int, int> {...}`

This way, CMyMap is strongly typed - I just can't pass any `CMap<int, int>` into a method that takes a CMyMap as a parameter.  typedef just tells the compiler "another name for", but class definition defines a new type.

If I defined a function
void foo(const CMyMap &map);

but I used typedef to define CMyMap, e.g.
`typdef CMap<int, int> CMyMap;`
then someone could do
`CMap<int, int> myMap;`
foo(myMap);
and the compiler would be quite happy.

But if I really want foo to be strongly typed and ONLY take CMyMap, then inheritance is my mechanism of choice for "typing".

BTW, CMyMap is kindof generic, but something more specific might be CPhoneNumber2Index where the phone number is represented as an integer and the index is an integer.  It is obvious here that my CPhoneNumber2Index  is not just a map from an integer to another integer.  So foo might be
string ReverseLookup(const CPhoneNumber2Index &PhoneBook, int iPhoneNumber);
which shows that ReverseLookup has something to do with phone numbers, not `CMap<int, int>`

Answer (score 0):

After some heavy messing with templates, typedef behaves like normal variable assignment...