# Should I avoid typedef, try to use primitive names and cast when possible?

Tags: c++, winapi, types, casting, typedef

I'm not sure of the vocabulary here, but hopefully I can make myself understood.

As I'm working through the winapi with a less-than-rock-solid knowledge of C++, I find a lot of typedef stuff that, for me, seems to overcomplicate the issue and add one more thing I have to remember.

For example, `UINT` instead of `unsigned int`, `HBITMAP` which turns out is just a `HANDLE`, and lots of others.

My question is, can / should I substitute the more generic version of the type when possible, and just cast it down when it's needed (and, what's this called)?

For example, I'd like to write

- `void SomeFunction(unsigned int some_int) { ... }` instead of `void SomeFunction(UINT some_int) { ... }`
- `HANDLE hBMP = LoadImage(...); ImageList_Add(... (HBITMAP) hBMP ...);` instead of `HBITMAP hBMP = ...`

Is this good for newcomers, bad practice in general, or what?

Comment: `HANDLE` isn't a native type either; it's a `typedef` of `void *`. I'd stick with the WINAPI types when using the WINAPI, though.

Comment: Types such as UINT exist so that the user of the library can become better decoupled from the compiler's implementation details.

Comment: I agree with you in part, but I believe these typedefs are there to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The Win32 API is actually C, not C++.

The distinction becomes more important if you consider stuff like MFC or ATL, both of which are "object-oriented", C++-only APIs.  And both of which are mercifully becoming (have become?) obsolete.

2) Microsoft likes to use lots of macros and typedefs.  I can't say whether that's "good" or "bad".  It's simply a fact of life.  And it'll become second nature to you if you work with Windows for any length of time.

3) Most importantly - Yes: you should definitely follow the Microsoft conventions when you use the Microsoft APIs.  Using "HANDLE" when the MSDN page says "HANDLE" is a Good Thing.  Similar advice holds for "LPxxx", "TRUE", "FALSE", "INVALID_HANDLE", "HRESULT" etc etc.  If that's what it says in MSDN, then that's what you should use.

Not only will it make your code more readable ... but, surprisingly often, it can also *prevent* subtle bugs you might cause by "second guessing" the "true type".

Do *not* try to "second guess" the types.  It's just a Bad Idea.

Following the standard conventions will make life easier, safer, more reliable and more portable.

IMHO...

Answer (score 6):

Please don't `typedef` the obvious (i.e. `UINT` for `unsigned int`). Rather, `typedef` to convey meaning. `UINT` no better than `unsigned int` (some may argue that it's shorter, but seriously, it's not *that* much shorter).

A `typedef` for a long name (like a `typedef` for `std::map<unsigned int, flost>::const_iterator`) is, in my opinion, okay, because it improves readability. `UINT`... not so much.

A `typedef` to convey specific meanings for specific types/uses (like `HANDLE`) are decent. `HANDLE` is, in my opinion, better than using raw `void*` because a) I don't care if `HANDLE` is a `void*`, b) it conveys its purpose.

A `typedef` for portability is nice (like a typedef for a 32-bit signed integer), as it allows for easier transitions between platforms/compilers.

Comment: Typedeffing  `UINT` for `unsigned int` is not used to make it shorter, it's rather for portability. If you typedef it as `unsigned int` on platform A, but then typedef it for another type on platform B, you will not have to rewrite your code as you normally would have to.

Comment: I'm not doing the typedefs :) just trying to keep dancing and not step on anyone's toes.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: If `UINT` isn't a `typedef` for `unsigned int`, then it's misleading, and if it is, it's pretty useless, seeing as `unsigned int` always means "unsigned integer" on any compiler/platform. A `typedef` for a 32-bit unsigned integer makes sense (because then it's more about the 32-bits than it is about the unsigned integer), but a `typedef` for an unspecified-sized unsigned integer is hardly portable.

Answer (score 4):

> **Is this good for newcomers, bad practice in general, or what?**

It is a bad practice. You should not use the actual types.

The typedef's are usually for portability on different platforms & compiler implementations. So you should refrain yourself from using actual types instead of the typedef'ed name. Using actual types will make your code more tightly coupled to the platform & compiler implementation you use, in fact it may not work correctly if this combination changes.

Also, the typedefed names are more intuitive and widely known to programmers than the actual types, which is an additional reason why you should stick to those.

Comment: For an explanation of how typedefs increase portability see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/516268/1599559).

Comment: On the other hand, using typedefs from Windows.h is the ultimate way of making your code non-portable.

Answer (score 2):

`Typedefs` are not only useful for portability, but also for future proofing. If MicroSoft decides at some point that `UINT` should be a `typedef` for an `unsigned long int` instead of an `unsigned int` then using `UINT` will make sure your code continues to work. This type of change is highly unlikely, especially with code from large companies like MS, but the idea still holds: `typedefs` are good for many kinds of abstraction. They are by no means bad, but you can occasionally find examples of poor usage. If you are using someone else's API, always use their `typedefs`. They probably have a good reason for the abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for using a typedef.

1. abbreviating some type: `typedef unsigned int UINT`
2. portability: `typedef int INT64`
3. readability: `typedef HANDLE HBITMAP`

I'd rather read `HBITMAP hBitmap = ...` than `HANDLE hBitmap = ...` for the same reason that I would (in general) not write `Animal dog = new Dog()` because being more specific can help the reader of your code and you're not losing anything here because according to the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) you can use the `dog` instance everywhere you can use an `Animal` instance.

You might also consider using [`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp) if you are using C++ with Boost, this basically creates a simple class, thus, giving you a real new type (which means that you cannot mix the uses like you can with `HANDLE` and `HBITMAP`.

---

What you describe as **casting** is not really casting, because the types are identical, a `typedef` only creates an alias, not a new type. So, writing

`HANDLE hOtherBitmap = /* some code */;`

HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP) hOtherBitmap;

is like writing

`int i = /* some value */;`

int k = (int) i;

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - those are good points.  It just seems that with typedeffing, there's another level of complexity to keep track of.  But message received - I'll use it!